# Jupyter Notebook / Labs files eventually freezing, hanging, crashing - but still running

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I’m having an ongoing issue with Jupyter Notebook files appearing to ‘hang’ or ‘freeze’ after running for an extended period of hours/days - even though they still appear to be running and outputting as expected.

I’ve had the same issue running these files in Mac Safari, Google Chrome and as of this weekend in the standalone/desktop version of Jupyter Labs.

Initial research online shows there’s lots of similar issues being reported over the years but I’m not currently seeing anything that jumps out as possible cause or solution for my case.

Specifically - I have 3 Jupyter files running at the same time. The first 2 files pull data from websockets that update every 2 seconds via `asyncio` and write that data to dictionaries, the 3rd file runs in a loop via `scheduler` that updates every second and reads the data in those dictionaries via the `%store` IPython magic and then writes data to a csv file on the same machine as the Jupyter files are running.

At some point, after running for hours/days - one or more of the Jupyter files appears to hang or freeze. Sometimes the little [*] disappears from the cell that was running, sometimes the UI freezes, sometimes the tab won't load and all I see is a blank tab.

I can’t link the issue to one particular file or any particular code.

However - it appears that all the code is still running as I’m still able to see the websocket is connected and pulling data (I set up a test file to manually check datetime stamps) and I’m still seeing data being written to the csv file (I can see the last modified date on the csv file).

The output dictionaries only have about 10-15 key/value pairs and are limited to 450 values and the output csv file is generally less than 100 lines before this issue occurs - so I’m assuming the size of the data set is not the issue.

I’ve tried all the basic ‘don’t go to sleep’ options in both Safari and Chrome and on my MacBook system settings. I’ve now had this issue under Mac OS 10.15 and 12.6. I don’t feel like the Mac itself is becoming unresponsive - although Safari definitely got very sluggish when this issue happened there which is why I started using Google Chrome.

Ideally, these files need to run 24/7 and I was hoping that swapping from Jupyter Notebooks to Jupyter Labs might sort this but after running these files for the past few days for the first time in Jupyter Labs - I’ve just come home to exactly the same issue and this time Jupyter Labs looks like it had crashed.

I’m running Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda and the stand-alone desktop version Jupyter Labs is also using that Kernel.

Running Python 3.9.13, not seeing any other Python-related issues.

Can anyone help with either a solution to this or some pointers for digging in and troubleshooting this in more detail?

Comment: What happens if you take jupyter out of the equation and just sue python?  My personal opinion is that jupyter is for interactive testing, not for multi-day production runs.

Comment: As JonSG is pointing at, **in general** Jupyter is less suitable for long computation. Although there are things you can do to improve it as the developers have offered kernels that will run on separate from the connection. If you aren't aware of these things though and starting out you'd probably benefit more by investing your time learning about running from the command line in combination with tools like screen or tmux.

Comment: See [here](https://twitter.com/KyleRayKelley/status/1647439683759280133) and [here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1643663336285040640) about this special, non-standard stuff I referenced. Using screen or tmux or a similar tool and on the command line though will be a much more transferable skill.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the advice I got in the comments on my original question - I started running the files that were giving me issues in Jupyter's Qt Console and that seems to have solved the problem.

I can now launch and run them continuously for weeks at a time without any apparent issues.

Still not sure what the exact cause of the problem is/was - but getting them out of Jupyter Notebook and running them in the Qt Console appears to be a fix and it let me keep using the IPython Magics which were a critical part of the files.